# Не могу зарегистрироваться в Azue

Tags: azure, azure-websites

Всем привет, может кто сталкивался и уже имеет ответ на данный вопрос. Прохожу курс по Azure и там необходим аккаунт есть 2 варианта  - бесплатный пробный и pay as go. Так вот ни в один меня не регистрирует. Нахожусь в Беларуси, может кто сталкивался с такими проблемами, не нашёл информации о том, чтобы майкрософт закрыл доступ РБ и РФ.

P.s - пробовал под 3-мя разными аккаунтами и пробовал привязывать разные карты[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На скрине написано, что нет прав на использования аккаунтом.

Microsoft приостановил продажу товаров и услуг. Написано для России, но похоже там не разбирались и заблокировали для двух стран, либо где-то есть дополнительная информация.

- https://blogs.microsoft.com/on-the-issues/2022/03/04/microsoft-suspends-russia-sales-ukraine-conflict/
- https://habr.com/ru/news/t/657601/
- https://devby.io/news/google-cloud-bolshe-ne-registriruet-novyh-polzovatelei-iz-rossii

Попробуйте использовать VPN для бесплатной версии. Возможно для платной версии вам понадобится карта/счет другой страны, если оплата не будет проходить.